# Xamarin Forms Get Value

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a class.

```
  public class A
{
   public int id{get;set;}
   public string name {get;set;}
}
```

**xaml**

```
    <Picker x:name="picker1" ItemsDisplayBinding = "{Binding name}" ItemsSource="{Binding SomeClass}" SelectedIndexedChanged="fun"/>

<Picker x:name="picker2" ItemsDisplayBinding = "{Binding some_val}" ItemsSource="{Binding A}"
```

**xaml.cs**

```
fun()
{
var value = picker1.Items[picker1.SelectedIndex];
}
```

In Picker 1 if I set ItemsDisplayBinding = {Binding name}, then the value in the picker contains "NAMES"

In Picker 1 if I set ItemsDisplayBinding = {Binding id}, then the value in the picker contains "ID"

The issue is I want to DISPLAY "names" in picker1 but want the value of the corresponding "ID". How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just cast to the correct class and select the "id" property

```
fun()
{
  var value = ((MyClass)picker1.Items[picker1.SelectedIndex]).id;
}
```

Comment: Getting error "Cannot convert type 'string' to <app_name>.<class_name>.

Comment: I assume that ItemsSource is a List<MyClass>.  If not, what is it?

Comment: Yes it is.
`HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(RestURL);
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(content);
picker1.ItemsSource = foo;`